# Google maps containsLocation on android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I'm writing an app that needs to determine whether a user falls within one of several defined zones (based on gps location).

The Google maps javascript API has an easy to use function [containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation). However I want to be able to do this from an app on android, not a web-based service. Does anyone know if such a call exists in the android version of maps? Any pointers will be helpful!

Comment: There is `LatLngBounds.contains()`, but only for "square" areas. What is the shape of these zones?

Comment: Thanks. I know of `LatLngBounds.contains()`, but these zones are not square, unfortunately.

Comment: What are they exactly? :) If circles, you can just calculate distance to the center. If polygons, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405593/polygon-touch-detection-google-map-api-v2

Comment: Yes, that is something you can do without any services.  Lat and lng are just numbers; you can calculate something like Pythagoras (you have to multiply the longitude by cosinus(lat) ).  How are these zones defined?

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but here's the answer: [com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.containsLocation()](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) from Google Maps Android API utility library.

Comment: exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Geofencing feature for this purpose. The API's for that are a part of Google Play Services library and hence you can start using it by importing it into your app project.

It even gives the notification if a particular user has entered or exited a specific geofencing location in order for a developer to monitor the number of mobile devices entered in the zone he defined. The implementation is pretty simple, I am pasting some links that may guide you further.

This is Google's official documentation about Geofencing: 
http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

This [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps) actually implements an app for geofencing.

And this is another [link](http://www.plotprojects.com/?utm_expid=66248451-11.Cw6ggXUqTpukf9MyY0eJLw.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faclk%3Fsa%3Dl%26ai%3DCLOpdzbGUVIHVN4KFpQPjn4GQBonhy7YFyemNyr4BkbK4k_kBCAAQAWDJ7u2GyKOgGYgBAaABx9fP3QPIAQGpAqosBt50g7Q-qgQiT9D84gi_3V4SUoXUKWUMXLcau4rYrXPH1AWkr0nJWFjT5IAHoaiwIpAHAagHpr4b%26sig%3DAOD64_3SxjtcFOFpu13YtWb_79OhW2tWgw%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26ved%3D0CB4Q0Qw%26adurl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.plotprojects.com%2F) if you want to use a third party plugin in order to get geofencing in your app.

Hope this would help!!!

Comment: Thanks was searching for this