# check if point lies within a route path between two places

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I'm developing an android app and I have a route path generated from Google Directions API like this example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

I want to check whether a location X falls on the route or not.

How i can possibly do this ?

**NOTE:** After searching on Stackoverflow i found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501756/direction-api-check-if-a-place-falls-in-the-route-path-between-2-places) and it's similar to what i want to do but it is in JavaScript and from the answers i found a method in Google maps JavaScript APIs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation) that do what i want but it's not available for the Android API Library ,How can i use it on Android ?

Comment: Its a PITA, but you can use direct HTTP calls just like the javascript api does.

Comment: i have posted a wrong link of the javascript solution method and i have edited the question please check it again and if it is the same how can i accomplish the HTTP call like the API do i can't find a link to create a request on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556694/google-maps-containslocation-on-android/35980345#35980345) it an API for android from Google Maps utility API contain method containLocation()

```
com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.containsLocation()
```

from Google Maps Android API utility library.

Comment: What if I want to use this on server side not on client side?

Comment: @hrushilok depending on the server side stack, there is a lot of ports for google maps utilities but more awesome alternative you could use Turf more advanced one and would help you a lot with everything map/location related and have a lot of ports https://turfjs.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isLocationOnPath()` from android-maps-utils library.