# android google maps which polygon touched

Tags: android, google-maps

I am drawing multiple polygons in my app. I created a touch detection listener (Thanks to [matiash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82788/matiash) : [Polygon Touch detection Google Map API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405593/polygon-touch-detection-google-map-api-v2/34418732#34418732))
But how I know which polygon touched? in the detection listener I'm using polygon.getID() but I couldn't set this ID value. it is random. How can I set the ID.

polygon creation :

```
            Polygon bol = myMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                            .strokeColor(Color.argb(100,255,0,0))
                            .strokeWidth(3)
                            .geodesic(true)
                            .zIndex(1)
                            .clickable(true)
                            .addAll(koords)
            );
```

and the listener :

```
    myMap.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {
            // Handle click ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: code required to verify the issue... How are you creating polygon? through  code or trying to put marker in map and then based on multiple markers are you drawing?

Comment: the listener gives you the polygon touched as function parameter.
The ID is random if you do not assign one when creating the polygon (or later on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to store my polygon ID. I could not modify polygon's ID but it is possible to set a float value of polygon's zIndex.

I'm using integer part of zIndex for polygon's display order and the decimal part of zIndex for my ID value.

For example : 4.12322 4 is display order and 12322 is my ID.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution would be to build your own `CustomPolygon` class that extends `Polygon` and add an assignable unique identifier. Then use this class instead of Android's `Polygon`

Comment: Polygon is a final class